# ODBC Driver to Connect Sequel Pro to R

Tags: r, odbc, sequelpro

I'm attempting connect my Sequel Pro database to R. In Joseph Adler's "R in a Nutshell"- page 164- he lists various ODBC drivers for different databases, but I can't find one for Sequel Pro. Any help on which driver to use would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Sequel Pro is just a front end for MySQL, not a db itself. So you'd presumably connect using MySQL ODBC drivers in the same way you connected Sequel Pro to your MySQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Sequel Pro database, but here are the steps you would likely follow:

1. Install the proper ODBC driver (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)
2. Add the database as an ODBC DSN. This is available in Windows in Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC). (Enable by right-clicking on Start Menu, "Customize...", and select one of the display options under "System administrative tools".) Add the database under "File DSN" (most likely) or "User DSN".
3. Use R to open ODBC connection:

   ```
   library(RODBC)
   dsn <- "this is the dsn assigned in the windows tool"
   db <- odbcConnect(dsn)
   sqlQuery(db, "select * from whatever")
   sqlSave(db, df)
   ```

Data in `df`. Sorry I can't give you the exact process, but I don't have the necessary data.

Comment: Will the steps be the same for a mac?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-macosx.html

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-macosx.html